# mysqlpump generates incorrect create view queries

Tags: mysql

I use mysqlpump to backup database:

`mysqlpump --single-transaction --add-drop-database --skip-definer --databases mydatabase --result-file /opt/myservice/backup/export.sql`

My DB contains several views, and part of them are exported with totally incorrect SELECTs in CREATE VIEW queries like that one:

```
CREATE VIEW `careerpulse-staging`.`user_view` AS SELECT
 1 AS `id`,
 1 AS `name`,
 1 AS `department`,
 1 AS `manager_id`
;
```

Why is it happening and how can I fix that?

MySQL version is 5.7

Comment: Might be a bug in the software? Hard to say without the real view code..By the way did you also try it without `--single-transaction` en or `--skip-definer` option to see what the program exports then?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior, not a bug.  Review the *complete* dump file.

Views cannot be created that reference other views or tables unless those other views or tables already exist.

To eliminate potential circular dependencies, dummy views are created in the first pass, and after all the views and tables have been created, those dummy views are dropped and the real views are created in a second pass.

The correct view definitions should be found near the end of the dump file.

Comment: That is exactly complete dump file I'm looking at. Some views are exported correctly, with correct view definitions. But some of them was exported ONLY as dummy views, without any correct definitions.